# string.match() with wildcard of unknown length

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to use `string.match()` to find values in a javascript string. Part of the value to match contains unknown characters. If I know there are two unknown characters, I can do the following.

```
string.match(/foo..bar/);
```

My question is, if I don't know the length of the unknown (whether I need `.` or `..` or `...`), is there a regex way to do this? The only solution I know of is to call `string.match()` multiple times, just curious if there's a better one.

Comment: `.*` matches any number of characters. To learn the basics of regular expressions, have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Comment: `.*?` to be non-greedy and stop on the first occurence of bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any charater, use "." and if it can occur 0 or more times (any no of times) then use the "*" which is a greedy operator in regex. So, you can use:-

```
string.match(/foo.*bar/);
```